# Exception:Missing the manifest.properties

Tags: java, exception, opennlp

I am new to **opennlp**, I am getting **Missing the manifest.properties!** exception when i excute the following code,please tell me suggestion to avoid this.

```
   public class PrePostProcessing_Peregrine  {


public Map<String,Set<String>> btntMap;
public Map<String, String> fishMap;
public SentenceModel sModel;
public SentenceDetectorME sentDet;
public Map<String,Set<String>> topBottomTermSet;

public PrePostProcessing_Peregrine() throws IOException {


    FileInputStream str=new FileInputStream("/home/rajendraprasad.yk/Desktop/data/en-sent.bin");
    System.out.println(str+"===================>");
     SentenceModel sModel = new SentenceModel(str);
     System.out.println("===================model =================>"+sModel);
    sentDet = new SentenceDetectorME(sModel);
    System.out.println("===================>sentDet "+sentDet);
    System.err.println("Sentence Detector Initialized");
```

Exception is:

```
opennlp.tools.util.InvalidFormatException: Missing the manifest.properties!
    at opennlp.tools.util.model.BaseModel.validateArtifactMap(BaseModel.java:217)
    at opennlp.tools.sentdetect.SentenceModel.validateArtifactMap(SentenceModel.java:78)
    at opennlp.tools.util.model.BaseModel.<init>(BaseModel.java:142)
    at opennlp.tools.sentdetect.SentenceModel.<init>(SentenceModel.java:73)
    at com.molcon.Text_Mining.PrePostProcessing_Peregrine.<init>(PrePostProcessing_Peregrine.java:66)
    at com.molcon.Text_Mining.TextMining.peregrineRun(TextMining.java:207)
    at com.molcon.Text_Mining.TextMining.process_journals_for_Mining(TextMining.java:108)
```

I made mistake at `FileInputStream modelIn = new FileInputStream("/home/rajendraprasad.yk/Desktop/data/en-sent.bin");` now I changed to `InputStream modelIn = new FileInputStream("/home/rajendraprasad.yk/Desktop/data/en-sent.bin");` from this changes am not getting any exception but not able to load file from **SentenceModel**.

when i execute this line `SentenceModel sModel = new SentenceModel(modelIn);` am not getting any response,please help

Comment: It would help if knew the exact version of OpenNLP you are using. Checking the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.opennlp/opennlp-tools/1.5.3/opennlp/tools/util/model/BaseModel.java) points to a serialization issue - the `manifest.properties` wasn't serialized into the file, and it's created in one of the constructors, but not the one that uses `InputStream`.

Comment: the version am using here 1.5 OpenNlp

Comment: It seems you are not using OpenNLP 1.5.0, debug line numbers don't match.

Comment: sorry...the version is OpenNlp 1.5.2 its working fine in eclipse but in the case of tomcat server

Answer (score 1):

For what I know there are two possible causes:

- the model you are using is corrupted, try to download it again
- the version of the model and of the OpenNLP library that you are using are not matching. As I read from the official website models are version specific, so you should try to understand if this is you case, and act accordingly.

Comment: its working fine when execute using main method but not in the case of tomcat server

Comment: Then the problem is related to the tomcat/webapp configuration. You should provide a MANIFEST.MF file, or at least check if the various paths are correct.

Comment: I have put full code here and I am not getting any response when this following code executes: SentenceModel sModel = new SentenceModel(str); even exception also not coming

Comment: I am not aware of MANIFEST.MF file.could you please tell me where should i put that file in my application.thanks in advance.

Comment: I made mistake at FileInputStream modelIn = new FileInputStream("/home/rajendraprasad.yk/Desktop/data/en-sent.bin"); now I changed to InputStream modelIn = new FileInputStream("/home/rajendraprasad.yk/Desktop/data/en-sent.bin"); from this changes am not getting any exception but not able to load file from SentenceModel.

Comment: when i execute SentenceModel sModel = new SentenceModel(modelIn); this lime am not getting any response from server.

Comment: @Rajendra_Prasad you're right, I also used InputStream instead of FileInputStream. However what to you mean with "not getting any response from server". If the SentenceModel doesn't trow a null (or other) exceptions, it means that it has been initialize correctly.

Comment: Ya, am printing sModel but its not printing anything. and the same code executes fine when i used main method but its not working in server

Comment: Sorry, but at this point I think that a more deep and complete debugging is required in order to understand what is the problem and where exactly it is.

Answer (score 1):

If you check [this constructor](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.opennlp/opennlp-tools/1.5.3/opennlp/tools/util/model/BaseModel.java#115) you will see that `manifest.properties` is not a file, it is a set of hard-coded properties:

```
Properties manifest = new Properties();
manifest.setProperty(MANIFEST_VERSION_PROPERTY, "1.0");
...
artifactMap.put("manifest.properties", manifest);
```

When you compare it to the [`InputStream` constructor](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.opennlp/opennlp-tools/1.5.3/opennlp/tools/util/model/BaseModel.java#175) you can see that `manifest.properties` is nowhere to be found, only `loadModel(in)` which leads to conclusion that `manifest.properties` should be in the model file.

Why this works in a standalone application and not inside Tomcat requires some debugging.

As @5agado suggested, your model's version might be different than the library's.

Comment: I made mistake at FileInputStream modelIn = new FileInputStream("/home/rajendraprasad.yk/Desktop/data/en-sent.bin"); now I changed to InputStream modelIn = new FileInputStream("/home/rajendraprasad.yk/Desktop/data/en-sent.bin"); from this changes am not getting any exception but not able to load file from SentenceModel.

Comment: when i execute SentenceModel sModel = new SentenceModel(modelIn); this lime am not getting any response from server.

Comment: Like @5agado said, it is time for some real debugging: see how the model is loaded in stand-alone mode, and compare it with how it's done in Tomcat.